# Chaining N AngularJS promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have written Saving code for a controller.  The amount of work is variable and can either be a `delete`,`add` or `edit` action.  I want them to be done in that specific order so would like to, somehow, create a promise chain that does each action after the other i.e.

1. Process all `delete` actions, in order
2. Process all `add` actions, in order
3. Process all `edit` actions, in order

Currently my code looks like this

```
// Save deleted groups first
angular.forEach(listOfDeletedGroups, $scope.saveGroupDelete);

// Now save added groups
angular.forEach(listOfAddedGroups, $scope.saveGroupAdd);

// Now save any edits
angular.forEach(listOfChangedGroups, $scope.saveGroupEdits);
```

My save methods are all very similar, and look like this:

```
$scope.saveGroupDelete = function (group) {
    groupAPIService.deleteGroup(group)
        .success(function () {
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.savingInfo.numErrors++;
        })
        .finally(function () {
            $scope.savingActionComplete(group);
        });
};
```

I know I can use `$q` to make these functions return promises that I could use with `.then()`

```
$scope.saveGroupDelete = function (group) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    groupAPIService.deleteGroup(group)
        .success(function () {
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.savingInfo.numErrors++;
        })
        .finally(function () {
            $scope.savingActionComplete(group);
            deferred.resolve();
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

But I dont know how I can chain up these requests to ensure they happen in order, one after each other for N promises.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704745/how-do-i-sequentially-chain-promises-with-angularjs-q help?

Comment: Looks great.  Does the chain start executing straight away or do I have to execute it somehow?

Comment: It starts running immediately. Wrap it in a function and call it when necessary.