# Angularjs $q run in sequences

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Got an issue with **angularjs** and some promises. For some reason, my services mix answers on queries, and while services are fixed I need to change my $q.all() to instead of running all promises asynchronously, **run then in sequence.**

Right now, it looks like this :

```
var promises = [p1, p2, p3];

$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    // All promises are done
}).catch(function (exception) {
    // An error occured.
});
```

Expected behaviour should be like `p1.then(p2).then(p3);`, and order does not matter (since normally run async). Array lenght is variable.

Since $q is inspired by Q lib, I looked in Q documentation and found [a sequence reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences) but couldn't make it work with $q.

Can anyone recommand an easy solution for such issue ?

I did tryed this `promises.reduce($q.when, $q(initialVal));` but don't understand what initialVal refere to :(

Thanks for reading, and have a nice day.

Comment: something needs to fire off these asynchronous requests. So first of all group these functions and order them in priority. Next, wire up each resolve to fire off the next function. I would just create your own service which does this.

Comment: Yes my first idea would be a recursive function to trigger the first one, then pop the array and call again after succeed. Not a lot of coding, but not really js style I am affraid. If I do not have an answer, I'll do something by myself and publish here (addd in $q prototype for easy re-use)

Comment: `initialValue` is the input into the first async function in the array, except, I don't think you need `$q` there

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sequentially chain promises with angularjs $q?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704745/how-do-i-sequentially-chain-promises-with-angularjs-q)

Comment: Damned, sorry for duplicate ... don't know why I could not find it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have promises, the asynchronous methods are already fired! You have to fire them one by one, so your array needs to contain functions that return promises rather than promise objects.

You can then go about it like this, which is clearer to me than the shortcut from Q you provided in your question:

```
var promiseReturningFunctions = [p1, p2, p3];
var queueEntryPoint = $q.defer();
// create a waiting queue
var queue = queueEntryPoint.promise;
// this queues up the asynchronous functions
promiseReturningFunctions.forEach(function (p) {
    queue = queue.then(p);
});
// here we start processing the queue by resolving our queueEntryPoint
queueEntryPoint.resolve();
// we can now use queue.then(...) to do something after all promises in queue were resolved
queue.then(function () {
    // All promises are done
}).catch(function (exception) {
    // An error occured.
});
```

Comment: where is `promiseReturningFunctions` being used?

Comment: My bad, i was changing variable names for better teaching and left one out, see my edit.

Comment: It looks fine. Resolved entry point can be added with '$q.when()'. And it will need additional measures for supplying object methods as 'then' callbacks.

Comment: The entity which inserts into the intial array has to take care of proper binding, if the asynchronous callback function `foo.bar` makes use of `this`, then you would just add it to the array as `promiseReturningFunctions.push(foo.bar.bind(foo))`. I see no real reason for downvote.

Comment: Ok it works really nice in my case, thanks a lot for your help ;)

Comment: I found I had to make the promiseReturningFunctions factory functions, otherwise it would not work properly (execute immediately and not in sequence). See the possible duplicate question mentioned in the comments section of the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704745/how-do-i-sequentially-chain-promises-with-angularjs-q