# Create an empty JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm currently trying to create a tool to chain a dynamic amount of promises. Here is my code:

```
// NB: This is made using angular's $q, but this applies to anything else
promiseChain = function(array, passedPromise) {
    let chain = $q((resolve, reject) => resolve());
    for (let elem of array)
      chain = chain.then(_ => passedPromise(elem));
    return chain;
};
```

and here is my testing code:

```
// This returns a timeout wrapped in a promise
let testFn = function(s) {
  return $timeout(function() {
    console.log(s);
  }, 500);
};

let promise = makePromiseChain([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], testFn);
promise.then(_ => console.log('finished'));
```

This works. However, what irks me is the first line of `promiseChain`:

```
$q((resolve, reject) => resolve())
```

Isn't there any other way to create an empty, self resolving promise, or to start the chain? I feel dirty using this code. :/

Comment: We normally use `Array.prototype.reduce()` for this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25730751/3478010

Comment: Your `passedPromise` must be a function, not a promise, otherwise `passedPromise(elem)` would throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use [`$q.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) or [`$q.resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve):

```
chain = $q.resolve(); // or the alias $q.when()
```

A ES6 promise resolve is `Promise.resolve()`, so using `resolve` instead of `when` might be easy on the next person looking at the code.